# Find amount of natural numbers generated from array of digit characters

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Good day.

I have an array of digit characters `['9','0']` or `['9','5','2','0','0','0']`. Need to find amount of all natural numbers with length equal to array size generated from a source array. For example for `['9','0']` it will be only `90` and answer is `1`.

If array has no 0 and digits duplication amount of numbers can be calculated by factorial:

`['5','7','2'] => 3! => 6`

`['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'] => 7! => 5040`.

When zeros and duplication appears it's become changeable.

**More examples**: https://www.codewars.com/kumite/5a26eb9ab6486ae2680000fe?sel=5a26eb9ab6486ae2680000fe

Thank you

P.S. Better to find formula, I know how solve this problem by loops

`def g(a)
  answer = a.permutation(a.size)
  .select{|x| x.join.to_i.to_s.split("").size == a.size }.to_a.uniq.size
   answer
end`

Comment: What is the maximum length of the array? And you also should mention clearly if you would count only the 'unique' values or duplication is allowed.

Comment: provide some more examples or test cases

Comment: For duplicate :factorial(length of array)/ factorial(no. of duplicates in array)

Comment: unclear what you're asking: do you need a count of numbers or all those numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The only difference with '0' is that you can't have leading '0', aka first digit cannot be 0.

The formula given an array of N numbers become
(N - Number of zeros) * (N-1)!

When there is no zero, it is just N!.

Now consider the case with duplication, lets say there are K '1' in the array. For every permutation you have in the previous calculation, you can swap the '1' in K! permutation, thus you need to divide your result with K!. This need to be done for every single digits with duplicates. When there is no duplication (0 or 1 such digit), you are dividing by 0! or 1! thus division does not change the value.

Sample case: [0, 0, 1, 1]

4 digits, 2 zeros, 2 ones

(4-2) * 3! / (2! * 2!) = 3

Possible permutation: 1001, 1010, 1100

Comment: Ruby has no factorial method. Rather than rolling your own, you can use [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation): `[1,2,3,4,5,6].permutation(6).size #=> 720 (= 6*5*4*3*2). Note that `permutation` returns an enumerator (not an array) that is equipped with optimized (C) code to respond to `size`. For example, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].permutation(9).size` returns `362880` in the blink of the eye.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you this  is very useful comment. I appreciate for this comment, it will helps in future using Ruby a lot.

Comment: @lamady thank you for your answer. It did not test it yet. But it give data to work with.

Comment: @lamandy I tested it ones, but it dose not pass a tests, may be some where is an error: https://gist.github.com/lbvf50mobile/21c2e668dd0db89838c2bf374fa5ee3a